# Using std::sort with custom class

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I have created a minimum reproducible example below:

Polygon3D.h:

```
#pragma once
class Polygon3D
{
public:
    // Constructors
    Polygon3D();
    Polygon3D(const Polygon3D& p);
    // Accessors
    void SetAverageZ(float average);
    float GetAverageZ() const;
    // Operators
    Polygon3D& operator= (const Polygon3D& rhs);
    const bool operator< (const Polygon3D& rhs) const;
private:
    float _averageZ;
};
```

Polygon3D.cpp file:

```
#include "Polygon3D.h"
// Default constructor
Polygon3D::Polygon3D()
{
    _averageZ = 0;
}
// Copy constructor
Polygon3D::Polygon3D(const Polygon3D& p)
{
    _averageZ = p.GetAverageZ();
}
// Accessors
void Polygon3D::SetAverageZ(float average)
{
    _averageZ = average;
}
float Polygon3D::GetAverageZ() const
{
    return _averageZ;
}
// Operators
Polygon3D& Polygon3D::operator=(const Polygon3D& rhs)
{
    return *this;
}
// Used by std::sort to order lists of this class
const bool Polygon3D::operator<(const Polygon3D& rhs) const
{
    return _averageZ < rhs.GetAverageZ();
}
```

Sort.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Polygon3D.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<Polygon3D> list;

    Polygon3D temp1 = Polygon3D();
    temp1.SetAverageZ(2);
    list.push_back(temp1);

    Polygon3D temp2 = Polygon3D();
    temp2.SetAverageZ(0);
    list.push_back(temp2);

    Polygon3D temp3 = Polygon3D();
    temp3.SetAverageZ(6);
    list.push_back(temp3);

    Polygon3D temp4 = Polygon3D();
    temp4.SetAverageZ(5);
    list.push_back(temp4);

    std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), std::less<Polygon3D>());

    std::cout << "Sorted vector: ";

    for (Polygon3D poly : list) 
    {
        std::cout << poly.GetAverageZ();
    }
}
```

And this is the output I receive:

```
Sorted vector: 2065
```

As you can see, the vector is not being sorted and is output in the order the items are added. Is there a reason why this is not being sorted correctly? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: *I can see that the sort itself isn't working and believe there may be an issue with pointers* -- There are no pointers in the code you posted.

Comment: "_I can see that the sort itself isn't working_" How? Show us the error or explain the precise way it "isn't working".

Comment: From just this bit of code, that would imply that GetAverageZ() isn't working as intended, or you created the vector already sorted. The issue isn't the sort call. Are the GetAverageZ functions const as well?

Comment: Psychic debugging: `_polygons` is a `std::vector<Polygon *>` and you need to dereference in the compare, e.g. `return lhs->GetAverageZ() < rhs->GetAverageZ();`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a copy assignment operator which doesn't actually copy assign the `_averageZ` member. `std::sort` will be using that to exchange elements of the vector, but because it doesn't actually change any members, the sorting of the `_averageZ` members in the vector will be unchanged.

You need to always implement the special member functions properly when you declare them.

The compiler does however define a copy assignment operator that does the correct thing for you implicitly [as long as certain conditions are met](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator).

Just remove your user-provided copy assignment overload and copy constructor definitions and declarations from the class and it will work as expected, i.e. remove `Polygon3D(const Polygon3D& p);` and `Polygon3D& operator= (const Polygon3D& rhs);` and their implementations. Then the compiler will define a correctly working copy constructor and copy-assignment constructor for you implicitly.

But if you must have these special member functions declared, then you need to actually copy the `_averageZ` member in the copy assignment overload.